# How to use .animate() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope you could check my code. Just want to animate. Toggle the top position of div tag with 'accordionHeader' class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordionHeader").toggle(function() {
      $(".accordionHeader").animate({"top": "0 144px"}, 500);
      function(){
        $(".accordionHeader").animate({"top": "144px 0"}, 500);
      );
  });
</script>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: wrong `top` value. You should do something like `top: '144px'` and `top: '-144px'`. [Explanation about top](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/top).

Comment: why is there a zero ??!!!! the top property only takes one number

Answer (score 1):

you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".accordionHeader").toggle(
     function(){
        $(".accordionHeader").animate({"top": "144px"}, 500);
     },
     function() {
        $(".accordionHeader").animate({"top": "-144px"}, 500);
     });
});
```

As an alternative, since [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is deprecated, you could also do:

```
$(".accordionHeader").on("click", function() {
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    if (clicked) {
        $(".accordionHeader").animate({"top": "144px"}, 500);
    }
    else {
        $(".accordionHeader").animate({"top": "-144px"}, 500);
    }
    $(this).data("clicked", !clicked);
});
```

Comment: However that is what the OP used.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on click event

```
 $('.accordionHeader').animate({ position: 'relative', top: '144px' }, 500);
```